# How to create the primary index via curl in Couchbase?

Tags: curl, couchbase, sql++

I want to configure my Couchbase instance via curl commands within a sh script. I already figured out how to set up a cluster, add a node, a user and a bucket. But the primary index is not set properly.

I use the following command to create the index for my default bucket but it only responds with a 404. I tried it with authentication params (`-u admin:password`) as well but it did not work either.

```
curl -v http://localhost:8093/query -d statement=CREATE%20PRIMARY%20INDEX%20primary_index%20ON%20default:default%20USING%20GSI
```

Comment: I think the path should be /query/service. And make sure it is a HTTP POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comment @geraldss. This worked for me so my working query looks like this:

```
curl -X POST -v -u $ADMIN:$DEFAULT_PASSWORD http://localhost:8093/query/service -d statement=CREATE%20PRIMARY%20INDEX%20primary_index%20ON%20default:default%20USING%20GSI
```